# Android Studio - Loading RecyclerView from SQLite Database entering a word in Edittext

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-recyclerview, android-edittext

I'm working on Android Studio and I have a table with 3 records uploaded on the DB SQLite in my project.

```
public class BaseDeDatos extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

public BaseDeDatos(Context context, String s, Context applicationContext, int i) {
    super(context, "verbos.db", null, 10);
}

@Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL("create table verbos(id integer, verbos text, referencia text, eu text, voce text, nos text)");
        db.execSQL("insert into verbos values(1, 'agito', 'abalo', 'abala', 'abalamos', 'abalam')," +
                "(1, 'agito', 'abalava', 'abalava', 'abalávamos', 'abalavam')," +
                "(1, 'agito', 'abalei', 'abalou', 'abalamos', 'abalaram')");
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int i, int i1) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS verbos");
        db.execSQL("create table verbos(id integer, verbos text, referencia text, eu text, voce text, nos text)");
        db.execSQL("insert into verbos values(1, 'agito', 'abalo', 'abala', 'abalamos', 'abalam')," +
                "(1, 'agito', 'abalava', 'abalava', 'abalávamos', 'abalavam')," +
                "(1, 'agito', 'abalei', 'abalou', 'abalamos', 'abalaram')");
    }
}
```

And this is my "Verbos2" activity where I'm working:

```
public class Verbos2 extends AppCompatActivity {

ArrayList<Item> listaItem;
RecyclerView recyclerViewItem;
EditText etVerbos;
Button mostrar;

BaseDeDatos conn;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.verbos2);

    etVerbos = findViewById(R.id.etIngresar);
    mostrar = findViewById(R.id.bnMostrar);

    listaItem = new ArrayList<>();
    recyclerViewItem=findViewById(R.id.rvListItems);
    LinearLayoutManager manager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    recyclerViewItem.setLayoutManager(manager);
    recyclerViewItem.setHasFixedSize(true);

    RecyclerViewAdapter adapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(listaItem);
    recyclerViewItem.setAdapter(adapter);

 //   recyclerViewItem.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));


    mostrar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            BaseDeDatos admin = new BaseDeDatos(getApplicationContext(), "verbos.db", getApplicationContext(), 10);
            SQLiteDatabase db = admin.getReadableDatabase();
            Item item = null;
            String[] parametros = {etVerbos.getText().toString()};
            Cursor cursor=db.rawQuery("select * from verbos WHERE verbos =?", parametros);

            while (cursor.moveToNext()){
                item = new Item();
                item.setVerbo(cursor.getString(0));
                item.setReferencia(cursor.getString(1));
                item.setEu(cursor.getString(2));

                listaItem.add(item);
            }
        }
    });

}
}
```

I'm trying to load my Recycler View with the data in my SQLite Database when I set the word "agito" in the EditText, (it should bring me the information of the 3 records in my database, because "agito" in the field "verbo" is in all records), but when I write and click on the button, nothing happens. There is no error, just nothing appears in the RecyclerView:

This is a picture of the recyclerview layout to understandme better:

[image]

This is my Recycler View activity:

```
public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter {
private ArrayList<Item> listItem ;

public RecyclerViewAdapter(ArrayList<Item> listItem) {
    this.listItem = listItem;
}

@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View contentView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.lista, parent, false);
    System.out.println("CREATE VIEW HOLDER: " + viewType);
    return new Holder(contentView);

}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Item item = listItem.get(position);
    Holder Holder = (Holder) holder;
    Holder.tvVerbo.setText(item.getVerbo());
    Holder.tvReferencia.setText(item.getReferencia());
    Holder.tvEu.setText(item.getEu());

    System.out.println("BIND VIEW HOLDER: " + position);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return listItem.size();
}

public class Holder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    TextView tvVerbo;
    TextView tvReferencia;
    TextView tvEu;


    public Holder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        tvVerbo = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvLista1);
        tvReferencia = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvLista2);
        tvEu = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvLista3);
    }
}
```

}

I think I'm missing something in "Verbos2" to get the data from my SQLite Database and load it into my Recycler View.

I'll be so gratefull if you could help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to set `attachToRoot` in `onCreateViewHolder` to `false`
Will be:

```
 View contentView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.lista, false);
```

Comment: I just solved the problem a few seconds before your respone, but thanks anyway! Now I have no error messages but I can't get what I need, (load my recycler view from my SQLite Database).
I edited the post to show this problem, if you see something I'm missing please tell me.

Comment: fine, try to log what you got from the cursor to know where is exactly the problem

Comment: How could I do that? there is no message in the log when I run the app

Comment: @RodrigoPaz please add breakpoint on your cursor and try debug code.Then you may know that what data you have in your cursror.

Comment: Search for "Log in android" and put a log message after calling the  Cursor to know if it has the data or not...in anther answer try to delete  Item item = null; then initialize it within the while statements like: Item item = new Item();

Comment: I did this but the log doesn't tell me nothing

Answer (score 0):

You are using context.getSystemService somewhere in your code.
The context you are using is null.

Comment: I searched in all the code but I don't have any context.getSystemService

Comment: @RodrigoPaz Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Object android.content.Context.getSystemService(java.lang.String)' this is the error you are getting. It might be possible that you are using getSystemService in your code for some type of service to run.

Comment: I solved that problem and now It don't fails but I have another problem (I edited the post). Nothing happens when I push the botton, and It should load the recycler with the info from my SQLite Database